# How do I filter out all documents in which a time field doesn't exist in PyMongo?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I am using the sample_airbnb database on MongoDB cloud with the listingsAndReviews collection and I am comparing the first_review field. I tried selecting for the documents in which the first_review field exists by using the $exists operator but it isn't working.

[image: the image of first_review]

(I'm trying to check if the first_review field here exists before running calculations on that)

I tried selecting for the fields in which the query exists by using the following query with $exists:

```
# Query documents where the first_revi9ew field exists, sort in ascending order, and limit to 100
cursor = collection.find({"first_review": {"$exists": True}})
cursor.sort("first_review", pymongo.ASCENDING).limit(100)
```

Instead I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\reading\mongodbReader.py", line 61, in read_mongodb
    cursor = collection.find({"first_review": {"$exists": True}})
TypeError: must be str, not dict
```

Comment: Can you post the full code? The code you provided currently seems working fine and not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/DogeDevYT/Leaderboard-API/blob/master/reading/mongodbReader.py

Comment: I posted the entire repository to github along with the supporting files, hope this helps

Comment: The code segment you provided is not exactly the same as the one in the github... You need to check if you correctly loaded the content in `data`, which seems reading from a local json config. You could be reading a dict instead of a str, which explains the error.

Comment: Sorry about that, in the code segment I provided I replacing comparing_field with "first_review" to simplify my explanation of the problem, but what do you mean I'm reading a dict instead of a string? In the comparing_field I am reading, whenever I output the value to console it returns "first_review" which means I am reading my local JSON config correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at your repo and you are not setting `collection` correctly; `collection` is a string. It needs to be a database collection.

It doesn't fail harder because `str` implements a find method. You can repro your exact error message with:

```
'a'.find({'b': 'c'})
```

errors:

```
  File "...string2.py", line 1, in <module>
    'a'.find({'b': 'c'})
TypeError: must be str, not dict
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I REALIZED THE VARIABLE FOR MY COLLECITON WAS "accessed_collection" NOT "collection"